# Kendo-schedule setting weekstart to monday and setting culture

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-scheduler

I am evaluating kendo-ui and i would like to configure the [views](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#configuration-views)  `views: [{type: "week", ...}, { type: "workweek", ...}, { type: "month", ...}]` of [kendo-ui scheduler](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/timeline) to always start with monday.

I found [Q: Setting first day of week to Monday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419587/) but is has no accepted answers and offered solutions did not work for me.

#### Trying to set workWeekStart

So after trying several things out i ended up with:

```
$("#scheduler2").kendoScheduler({        
  date: new Date("2014/12/1"),
  allDayEventTemplate: $("#event-template").html(),                
  timezone: "Etc/UTC",
  views: [{ type:"day", showWorkHours:true, workWeekStart:0}
   ,{type:"week", workWeekStart:1, workWeekEnd:5
               , showWorkHours:true, selected:true}
   ,{type:"workWeek", workWeekStart:1, workWeekEnd:0
               , showWorkHours: true, selected: true }                    
  ,{type:"month", workWeekStart: 2 }
  , "agenda"]
  ,dataSource: events1,
  resources: [ { field: "attendees", dataSource: people1, multiple: true } ]
});
```

As you can see this works for `type:"workWeek"` every week starts with a monday and since i set `workWeekEnd:0` it ends with sunday. Using the same configuration settings on `type:"week"` or  `type:"month"`  has no effect - the week always starts with a sunday.

[image: Kendo-ui schedulre workweek start mondays]

#### Trying to set the culture

I tried three configuration options (see // attempt # below)

```
// attempt 1
kendo.culture("de-DE");

$("#scheduler2").kendoScheduler({        
  date: new Date("2014/12/1"),
  culture: "de-DE",      // attempt 2
  allDayEventTemplate: $("#event-template").html(),                
  views: [{ type:"week", culture: "de-DE", // attempt 3
```

But none of them had any effect. The reason could be

- i am doing it wrong
- inside kendo.all.js i found only one culture preconfiguration  `kendo.cultures["en-US"]` so i am assuming i need to create an configuration myself or create / edit some localisation file

#### Questions

1. How can i set monday to be the first day of the week for the views types `type: "week" ... type:"month"`
2. How can i set the culture for the schedule widget
3. Do i have to create a localisation file or set up the desired culture "de-DE" by hand or are there more preconfigured cultures somewhere in the kendo-ui bundle that i can use?

#### Arrays for the code above

```
var people1 = [{ text: "Alex", value: 1, color: "blue" }
      , { text: "Bob", value: 2, color: "red" }
      , { text: "Charlie", value: 3, color: "yellow" }
      , { text: "Doris", value: 4, color: "green" }];

var events1 = [
    { id: 1, title: "Int A 2.12", start: new Date("2014/12/2 08:00 AM"), end: new Date("2014/12/2 09:00 AM"), isAllDay: false, attendees: [1, 2] },
    { id: 2, title: "Int B 2.12", start: new Date("2014/12/2 08:30 AM"), end: new Date("2014/12/2 10:30 AM"), isAllDay: false, attendees: [2, 3] },
    { id: 3, title: "Int C 2. - 5.", start: new Date("2014/12/2 08:30 AM"), end: new Date("2014/12/5 10:30 AM"), isAllDay: true,  attendees: [1] },
    { id: 4, title: "Int D 3. - 4.", start: new Date("2014/12/3 08:30 AM"), end: new Date("2014/12/4 10:30 AM"), isAllDay: true, attendees: [3] },
    { id: 5, title: "Int E 4.12", start: new Date("2014/12/4 10:00 AM"), end: new Date("2014/12/4 2:00 PM"), isAllDay: false, attendees: [1, 4] }];
```

Comment: Concerning the localization, I've seen in other tickets that people are having some success with the kendo-global project. You simply reference/load the appropriate language script after the kendo files have been loaded and all widgets will attempt to use that language. Might be worth a shot. https://github.com/loudenvier/kendo-global

Comment: @KyleM I tested it for the [editor control](http://plnkr.co/edit/WZKFT6jFKn61KCh9Zcwd?p=preview) and it worked. But it did not work for the schedule control. I assume that this is because at least the german [kendo.de-DE.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/loudenvier/kendo-global/master/lang/kendo.de-DE.js) does not contain definitions for the schedule control. But nonetheless i appreciate your pointer to the repo. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set start day of week as "Monday" put the below line of code before the scheduler declaration.

```
  kendo.culture().calendar.firstDay = 1;
  // and further down initialize the scheduler
  $("#yourID").kendoScheduler({                
      //    ...
```

This works both for month and week view.
Hope this helps.